# доказательство утверждения по эйлеровым циклам

Tags: математика, графы

недавно столкнулась с интересным утверждением:

> а) если в связном графе все вершины четны, то внем существует эйлеров  цикл
> б) если в связном графе не более двух вершин с нечетными степенями, то в нем существует эйлеров путь(путь, который можно нарисовать, не отрывая карандаша от бумаги)

Поискала информацию в интернете, но кроме непонятных формулировок через звезды ничего не нашла. Объясните пожалуйста, как это доказать!!!Заранее спасибо

Comment: Это доказывается по индукции. Начните с нечётной вершины и двигайте карандаш по любому свободному ребру. Продолжайте пока можете. Подумайте в какой вершине вы можете оказаться в конце - когда движение невозможно. Подумайте почему вы к этому моменту прошли по всем ребрам.

Comment: а если в графе все вершины четны

Comment: если нечетные вершины есть, то я начну и закончу в нечетных вершинах, но пока не понятно, почему я прошла по всем ребрам...

Comment: Если все вершины чётны, начните с любой вершины.

Comment: Предоположите что вы прошли не все рёбра. Тогда где-то на маршруте есть вершина из которой выходит два ребра по которым вы не ходили. Удалите из графа ваш текущий маршрут, пробегите по оставшимся рёбрам. Вы вернётесь в ту же вершину. Из двух маршрутов соберите новый, в нём будет больше рёбер. Повторяйте "удлинение" маршрута пока можете.

Comment: а что делать, если все вершины четны, но мы должны доказать существование эйлерового цикла

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Утверждение:** [регулярный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84) связный граф степени два - цикл.

Доказательство:

Индукция по числу вершин.

База: треугольник.

Индукционный шаг: пусть для *n*-вершинного графа это верно (*n ≥ 3*). Рассмотрим граф из *n + 1* вершины. Выберем любую вершину, удалим её саму и два ребра к её соседкам. Соседок соединим одним ребром. Получится регулярный граф степени 2 из *n* вершин. По индукционному предположению это цикл. Откатим наши изменения, получим цикл из *n + 1* вершины. **Доказано.**

**Утверждение:** в связном графе со всеми чётными степенями вершин есть [эйлеров цикл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB).

***NB** Доказательство ведётся для [мультиграфов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84).*

Доказательство: индукция по числу рёбер, число вершин (*m*) фиксировано.

База: граф-цикл из *m* рёбер.

Индукционный шаг: Пусть для всех графов с *n* рёбрами есть эйлеров цикл. Рассмотрим граф с *n + 1* ребром. В нём есть вершина степени больше двух (иначе это был бы цикл, а он не цикл, так как *n + 1 > m*). Выберем любые два ребра из этой вершины, удалим их, соседок в которые шли эти рёбра соединим одним новым ребром. Получится связный (мульти)граф с *n* рёбрами. По индукционному предположению в нём есть эйлеров цикл. В этот цикл входит новое ребро между соседками. Заменим его парой рёбер которые мы удаляли. Получится эйлеров цикл для графа с *n + 1* ребром. **Доказано.**

**Утверждение:** если в связном графе все вершины кроме двух имеют чётную степень, то в нём есть эйлеров путь начинающийся и завершающийся в этих двух вершинах.

Доказательство:

Соединим эти две вершины новым ребром. Получим связный (мульти)граф со всеми чётными степенями. В нём есть эйлеров цикл. В него входит новое ребро. Удалим его. Получим эйлеров путь в исходном графе. **Доказано.**